# Is it possible for this truck to get across the desert?

Tags: logic

An unlimited supply of petrol is available from a camp at one edge of a desert which is 800 miles wide but no petrol is available anywhere else. A truck can only carry enough petrol to travel 500 miles and is able to leave petrol to be collected later. (There is no limit on the size of such stocks and it should be assumed that no petrol is lost by evaporation or spillage.) Establish whether or not it is possible for the truck to get across the desert and, if it is, explain how.

Comment: Hint. Can you create a very large stash of petrol $100$ miles into the desert?

Comment: This is usually called the jeep problem.  It comes in many forms, but a search will turn them up.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks!